# Temporary object not getting created when exception is caught by reference?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception

```
class Error1
{

public:

int errorcode;
Error1(int x):errorcode(x){ cout<<"CTOR Error1"<<endl; }
//Error1(Error1& obj ){
//    errorcode = obj.errorcode;
//    cout<<"CopyCTOR Error1"<<endl;
//}
~Error1(){cout<<"DTOR Error1"<<endl; }
};

void fun()
{
cout<<"Inside fun"<<endl;
throw(Error1(5));
}

int main()
{
try{

    fun();
}
catch(Error1& eobj)
{
    cout<<"Error1 type occured with code:"<<eobj.errorcode<<endl;
}
cin.get();

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Inside fun

CTOR Error1

DTOR Error1

Error1 type occured with code:5

DTOR Error1
```

This output indicates that a Error1 object is copy constructed for the catch handler. Since copy constructor is not defined for Error1 object default copy constructor is used.

When i uncomment the commented section for defining a copy constructor i get the the following output.

```
Inside fun

CTOR Error1

Error1 type occured with code:5

DTOR Error1
```

Why is it that only one DTOR is getting called? Even if exception is caught by reference i believe a temporary is still created.

Comment: Looks like the output is dependent on the compiler and exception runtime implementation.  For instance, gcc 4.3.4 is not generating any temporaries for your first code example with the default copy-constructor.  You can see an example here: http://ideone.com/9QyLf

Comment: First of all if you define your DTOR as virtual, you'll get first behavior equal to the second one.

Comment: @klement: There's no polymorphic behavior happening here, so I believe using `virtual` DTOR's is unecessary

Comment: @Jason: I've arranged an experiment, and that the result I got in VS2010 - virtual makes both code sections work equally.

Comment: @klement: In gcc I get the same results without adding `virtual` ... so again, using the `virtual` keyword may be a quirk specific to VS2010, but it's "unnecessary" per the C++ language in general for this specific scenario ...

Comment: @Jason: But if temporaries are not getting created means only one exception object is being referred right? ie the exception object thrown is being referred in catch.

Answer (score 1):

What compiler are you using?

When you introduce (i.e. uncomment) your version of copy constructor with `Error1& obj` argument, the code is supposed to become invalid. `throw` is supposed to be able to create a copy of its argument, while your version of copy constructor disables copying of temporaries. The code is ill-formed. If your compiler accepts it, its is probably because it illegally allows binding non-const references to temporaries (I suspect it is MSVC++ compiler with extensions enabled).

The original experiment works as it is supposed/allowed to. The argument of `throw` is copied to an internal temporary which is later used to initialize `catch` parameters. Although the compilers are allowed to use your original temporary directly, extending its lifetime accordingly.

Comment: If he defines it as private it becomes invalid. He can still rely on default copy CTOR.

Comment: @klement: The user-defined CTOR from the OP takes a non-`const` reference type, which means it can't accept a temporary as an argument ...

Comment: @klement: Firstly, declaring any copy constructor disables the compiler-provided one (which is probably what you called "default"). Secondly, the code is invalid even with public copy constructor as long as the reference parameter is non-const.  Such copy-constructor cannot be used to copy temporaries, as I said already.

Comment: Sorry, somehow misread you answer. I thought that you're saying if we're commenting out the copy CTOR code becomes invalid.

Comment: @AndreyT. But even if i define the copy constructor to take const Error1& the results doesnt change

Comment: @rocky: Great. That simply means that the compiler responds to those changes in such weird way. In the first experiment is copied the object. In the second one it decided not to. Machine logic is often quite illogical. Both behaviors are perfectly legal from the language point of view. By introducing that constructor you somehow encouraged compiler to perform the temporary elimination more aggressively.

Comment: @AndreyT: Is the following throw valid ?  throw( const Error1(5) ). When i ran with this change the catch was able take the const object as the parameter without creating a temporary. I believe catch never does a implicit conversion from a const to non const.

Comment: @rocky: In C++ when you throw a `const` object, the language conceptually creates a temporary that is not `const`. I.e. const is automatically removed. So, in this case the compiler is required to throw `Error1`, not a `const Error1`. Now, whether the compiler was correct by not creating a temporary is a different question...

Comment: @rocky: Note that `throw/catch` already has some capabilities to work around the restrictions of the language. For example, you can do `throw 5` and `catch (int &)`. I.e. it allows you to bind a non-const reference to a temporary. This is already quite a feat, prohibited anywhere else in the language. Maybe it is also legal to perform temporary elimination even when the source object is const... but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @AndreyT: So when throwing a non const object as in the question compiler could have gone either way. But when a const object was thrown compiler should have created temporary

Answer (score -1):

There may be other errors, but what I see right now is that `throw(Error1(5));` creates a temporary (or `rvalue`) of type `Error1`. You want an `lvalue`, which means that you should either do `throw(*new Error1(5));` (which I believe will create a memory leak, but I may be wrong), or you could create a global `Error1` object and just throw that.

**PS:** I would be interested to know if `throw(*new Error1(5));` does create a memory leak, if anyone would like to comment. Does `catch` destroy the object it catches? If so I think you should be fine with just creating new `Error1`s whenever you need them.

Comment: what would be your catch like? You are throwing the dereferenced pointer right? So a if your catch is like catch(Error1 obj) or catch(Error1& obj) it will lead to memory leak.

Comment: if you manually deleted your `Error1` would it still leak memory?

Comment: I believe you cant do a manual delete unless you throw by pointer and catch by pointer

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. I will try that later, thanks.

Comment: Not a good idea ... if you ever write code that other people will use that throw dynamically allocated objects like this, by convention they will most likely write `catch` statements that take l-value references, and you will be 100% guaranteed to have code that leaks.  The exception runtime was created to handle temporary exception objects, so use the system the way it was designed and not try to out-smart it (and anyone else using your code).

Comment: @Jason +1. I guess I don't know as much as I should about exceptions. Thanks.